# Mapbox: Upload tiles from GeoTiff and add tiles as raster

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have to show Geo TIFF files(really one JPG file and more TIF files) on the map. They are high resolution files taken by drone.
I followed to "Upload a tileset to Mapbox with the Uploads API" https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/upload-curl/ and everything was ok so far.
Here's my result of "Retrieve upload status" and it says uploading was successful.

```
root@Mysrv:~# curl "https://api.mapbox.com/uploads/v1/steven921/{id}?access_token={security_token}"
{"id":"ckneprskq01dd28qk92qe0aml","name":"Traverse Bay","complete":true,"error":null,"created":"2021-04-12T14:51:29.328Z","modified":"2021-04-12T14:51:29.328Z","tileset":"steven921.traverse-bay","owner":"steven921","progress":1}
```

But I'm confusing at the next step.
It says in the https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles:

```
'tiles': [
'https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
],
```

And it says in the https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/raster-tiles/#retrieve-raster-tiles
`/v4/{tileset_id}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}{@2x}.{format}`
So my html is:

```
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script> ... 
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({ 
    container: 'map', // container id 
    style: { 'version': 8,
        'sources': {                 
            'raster-tiles': { 
                'type': 'raster',
                'tiles': [ 
                    'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/steven921.traverse-bay/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg' 
                 ], 
                 'tileSize': 256,
             } 
         },
         'layers': [ { 
             'id': 'simple-tiles',
             'type': 'raster',
             'source': 'raster-tiles',
             'minzoom': 0,
             'maxzoom': 22
          } ] },
      center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position 
      zoom: 2 // starting zoom
});
```

And I got the result as following:
[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLv6V.png)
When I modified

```
    'tiles': [ 
        'tiles': [`https://api.mapbox.com/v1/steven921.traverse-bay/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` 
    ],
```

It complains:

```
GET https://api.mapbox.com/v1/steven921.traverse-bay/3/2/3.png 401 (Unauthorized)
u @ mapbox-gl.js:31
Error: Unauthorized: you may have provided an invalid Mapbox access token. See https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#access-tokens-and-token-scopes
    at mapbox-gl.js:31
```

Then I added api key at the end but it's the same.

```
'tiles': [`https://api.mapbox.com/v1/steven921.traverse-bay/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoia2F5cnJvcyIsImEiOiJjam5menEyNDAxOTgxM2tzZjdiZ2w0NzdlIn0.Rt8pCUa3cqFYdvwkKMS7qw`
```

I have struggled more than couple of horsand googled but got nothing useful link.
Really appreciated if anyone can help and give me right tileset url.
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you changed the URL. you shouldn't have changed the "v4" to "v1". I think the following URL should work.

```
    'tiles': [ 
           'tiles': [`https://api.mapbox.com/v4/steven921.traverse-bay/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`],...
```